# Calls to phonegap.js won't work

Tags: javascript, ios, api, cordova, include

When my button is clicked, nothing happens.

```
    <button onclick="captureVideo();">Capture Video</button>
```

I've put phonegap-1.4.1.js in the WWW folder.

I've included `<script src="javascript/phonegap-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in my head section.

I did all the supporting functions, as per Phonegap API Docs' example.

```
<script>
        // Called when capture operation is finished
        //
        function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
            var i, len;
            for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
            }       
        }

        // Called if something bad happens.
        // 
        function captureError(error) {
            var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
            navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function captureVideo() {
            // Launch device video recording application, 
            // allowing user to capture up to 2 video clips
            navigator.device.capture.captureVideo();
        }
        </script>
```

My other calls to other external js all work fine. Just phonegap-1.4.1.js isn't working. What am I missing here?

EDIT

When I pasted the phonegap js inline, then all my calls to those functions worked fine. So, I've established that the problem was it never loaded from externally. Diviceready alerts will tell me the same thing. But it doesn't MAKE it load. So, the question remains, how can I get the external js to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is here:

> I've put phonegap-1.4.1.js in the WWW folder.

But you're including it in a different location:

> I've included `<script src="javascript/phonegap-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in my head section.

It's not loading because it expects to find the file inside a javascript directory, while you've put it in the www folder. Make a dir "javascript" inside the www folder, or remove "javascript" from the src in your script tag.

Comment: Yep that got it. Wow I feel dumb. I guess that's why its important to include code in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, you might wanna set this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `document.addEventListener ..` to ensure PhoneGap loaded, So Call init() method on your body onload

```
<body  onload="init()">
```

and put the below in your head tag

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var onDeviceReady = function() {
            alert("OnDeviceReady fired.");
        };

        function init() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Ok, I did those. But I didn't get the alert. I guess that means phone gap didnt load? So, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that deviceready event is firing. only after it fires would u be able to make phonegap api calls

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've established the problem was  the external js not loading. But I still don't know how to MAKE it load. Any ideas there?

Comment: if its not loading properly then maybe thr is a bug somewhere, stalling the proper initialization of phonegap, because of which deviceready is not firing. It'll help if u can share full code somewhere.